# Swift: I don't understand why this code hasn't memory leak

Tags: swift

This code print "choco's memory discard" as a result.

But I think this code has memory leak.
Because saveClosure function is pointing let choco's name from the stack. and Closure run is pointing the name in the heap. so let choco's refrence counting is 2.

Also var run is pointing savaClosure. So there is storng reference cycle. But the result is activating deinit.

What am I missing?

```
class Dog {
    var name = "choco"

    var run: (() -> Void)?

    func walk() {
        print("\(self.name) is running.")
    }

    func saveClosure() {

        run = {
            print("\(self.name) is running.")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self.name)'s memory discard")
    }
}


func doSomethiing() {
    let choco: Dog? = Dog()
}

doSomething()
//choco's memory discard
```

```
class Dog {
    var name = "choco"

    var run: (() -> Void)?

    func walk() {
        print("\(self.name) is running.")
    }

    func saveClosure() {

        run = {
            print("\(self.name) is running.")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(self.name)'s memory discard")
    }
}


func doSomethiing() {
    let choco: Dog? = Dog()
}

doSomething()
// Memory Leak
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no memory leak because your code does not call `saveClosure()`. This means that `run` remains `nil`.

If you change `doSomething` to call `saveClosure()` then there is a retain cycle, the `deinit` is not called and there is no message printed:

```
func doSomething() {
    let choco: Dog? = Dog()
    choco?.saveClosure()
}
```

By the way, there is no need for `choco` to be optional as it doesn’t affect the behaviour.

Comment: Oh I've got it. You saved me. If i didn't call saveClosure(), there was no reference count cause run remains nill. Thanks for your help :)